# Find and Modify Registry values based on Subkey Name

Tags: powershell, registry

Finding this PowerShell script difficult:

[Pic of my registry](https://imgur.com/a/WNs2GTS)

```
|
|__SyncRootManager
  |
  |____OneDrive!S-1-5-21-SID
  |          |_____UserSyncRoots
  |
  |____OneDrive!S-1-5-21-SID
             |_____UserSyncRoots
```

For every subkey called "UserSyncRoots" that is a child of OneDrive!S-1-5-21-SID (which are children of "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager"),
it contains just one Reg Value that is named "S-1-5-21-SID" - how would I modify each Reg Value to "C:\AnyOldPath"

I was using `Get-ChildItem` in a `foreach` loop but I think I am going down the wrong path completely. Thank you for any help you can give.

Edit, oops, forgot to add my code

```
$registry = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager" -Recurse
Foreach($a in $registry) {
    if ( $a.PSChildName -eq "UserSyncRoots" )
    {
        $subkeys = (Get-ItemProperty $a.pspath)
        #Get-ItemProperty - OK I'm lost here
    }
}
```

Comment: "I was using `Get-ChildItem` in a `foreach` loop but I think I am going down the wrong path completely" - you forgot to post the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested (don't have those keys), but assuming no permissions issues, this should work or be close:

---

*Edited 1/31/24 : Added filtering on ProviderName, removed hard-coded string from processing and replaced with variable, and modified some variable naems.*

---

```
###   Good idea to use single quotes unless string expansion is needed
$SyncMgrPath     = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager'
# adding regex for -Match filtering
$ProviderFilter  = '\\OneDrive\![\d\-]+$'  # <backSlash>OneDrive!<digitsAndDashes><endOfLine>
$TargetKey       = 'UserSyncRoots'
$NewValue        = 'C:\AnyOldPath'

Get-ChildItem $SyncMgrPath -Recurse |
  where PSParentPath -match $ProviderFilter |
    where PSChildName -eq $TargetKey |
ForEach-Object {
    $splat = @{
        'Path'  = $_.PSPath
        'Name'  = $_.Property[0]
        'Value' = $NewValue
        'Type'  = 'String'
    }
    Set-ItemProperty  @splat
}
```

Note that (based on your question) there is no testing for the entry's existence or current value -- if it exists, its value is changed, if it doesn't exist, it's created.

- [Registry value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=net-8.0)

  - Optional for strings and integers (`DWORD`), but necessary for other types.
  - Valid values

    - Binary
    - ExpandString
    - MultiString
    - None
    - QWord
    - String
    - Unknown

Comment: Keith, thank you very much. Something I should have made clear before (sorry!) is that the name contains a SID so it  actually looks like S-1-5-21-290288854-1059173022-670963354-1002. This name is different from PC to PC that I need the script to run on. Can it pattern match? In fact there is only one name/value pair under UserSyncRoots if that helps? Thanks again!

Comment: That helps immensly -- with only one entry (and no `(Default)` value), the name of the property will be the only string in the array returned by `$_.Property` . Answer edited...

Comment: P.S. Though not neeeded here, the `-Match` and `-Replace` operators use regular expressions, so all sorts of pattern matching is available when needed.

Comment: Works great Keith. Looks like the SyncRootManager key can be used by other Cloud Providers, so I really need to include a check that anything other than "OneDrive!*" subkeys are excluded.

Comment: Hi. Code edited to inclue filteromg on provider. It could be done in a single `where` with either a scriptblock containing a `-and` operator or building a more complex regex , but I like the cascading simple comparisons -- I think it makes the code easier to scan and edit/modify for other tasks. Thanks for marking my reply as `Answer`, an upvote wouold be great as well! :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with pipes but this also worked:

```
$regKeySet = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\SyncRootManager -Recurse
foreach($childKey in $regKeySet)
{   
   if( ($childkey.Name -like '*OneDrive!*') -and ($childKey.PSChildName -eq 'UserSyncRoots') )
   {
       $splat = @{
        'Path'  = $childKey.PSPath
        'Name'  = $childKey.Property[0]
        'Value' = 'C:\Users\Public'
        'Type'  = 'String'
    }
    Set-ItemProperty @splat
   }
}
```